# How to refer sibling element in JSON Javascript?

Tags: json, vue.js, javascript-objects, siblings

I have a json object for chart like below:

```js
{
  "results": [
    {
      "dataSets": {
        "One": {
          "label": "testLabel",
          "labels": "test",
          "data": [
            "10",
            "58"
          ]
        }
      },

      "chart": [
        {
          "key": "test",
          "label": "chart-1",
          "chartType": "bar",
          "order": "1",
          "dataSets": [
            {
              "style": "line",
              "key": "One"
            },
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get `dataSets` values like `label`, `labels`, `data` of “`one`”  in `chart`’s `dataSets` by providing “`one`” as key.

Is it possible to do in javascript or vue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json/ This question would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. But you will need to make a series of `Array.map()` to achieve this.

```js
const results = [{
  dataSets: {
    One: {
      label: "testLabel",
      labels: "test",
      data: ["10", "58"]
    }
  },

  chart: [{
    key: "test",
    label: "chart-1",
    chartType: "bar",
    order: "1",
    dataSets: [{
      style: "line",
      key: "One"
    }]
  }]
}];

const modifiedResult = results.map(result => {
  const outerDataSets = result.dataSets;
  result.chart = result.chart.map(chart =>
    chart.dataSets.map(innerDataSet => ({
      ...innerDataSet,
      ...outerDataSets[innerDataSet.key]
    }))
  );
  return result;
});

console.log(modifiedResult);
```

Also if you are working with Vue, I think its best to put the modification of `result` on the computed so it will always try to add those `dataSets` additional data to the chart's dataSets.

[Here a sample demo for implementation in Vue](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-cannon-jr8e2?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:699-1044).

Comment: This was really helpful! Thank you very much for sharing.